# Integer value assigned to character data type

Tags: java

```
// Demonstrate char data type
class CharDemo {
 public static void main(string args[]) {
   char ch1, ch2;

   ch1 = 88; // code for x
   ch2 = 'y';

   System.out.print("ch1 and ch2: ");
   System.out.println(ch1 + "" + ch2);
 }
}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: how 88 become X and when make changing of number it gives another char like 100 will change to D please help me to understand this line and thanks for helping.

Comment: the output:  ch1 and ch2: x y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Demonstrate char data type
class CharDemo {
    public static void main(string args[]) {
        char ch1, ch2;

        ch1 = 88; // 88 is the ASCII code for the character X. 
        ch2 = 'y';

        System.out.print("ch1 and ch2: ");
        System.out.println(ch1 + "" + ch2);
   }
}
```

By assigning the ASCII-value for a character to a char-variable you will get the corresponding character for that particular value when you print it out to the console.

[ASCII-table](http://www.asciitable.com)

Answer (score 0):

It is ASCII value of the character that is assigned to variable, so it is not 88.

In ASCII table, 88 stands for x

Answer (score 0):

> how 88 become X

88 is a char code that references of an ASCII table (simply put). If you want a full list of char codes, look at an ACSII table [like this one](http://www.asciitable.com/index/asciifull.gif)

If you look on the chart, 88 becomes capital X, and then 100 turns into lowecase d